# Error .NET Framework version 8 is not supported when add a Service Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I create a new Class Library project (.NET 4.5) in Visual Studio 2015 and try to add a Service Reference to a webservice, I received this error:

.NET Framework version "8" is not supported. Please specify a value from the enumeration Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.

I'm using VS 2015 Update 3. I checked and there are no updates available for Visual Studio neither for Windows 10. Any ideas?

Comment: That is... bizarre.

Comment: Clearly you'll have to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I find the problem, I'll share it with you. Very strange this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to temporarily solve the problem by opening in webservice compatibility mode, the advanced tab in adding service references.